# HTTP Header POST Request with Curl

Tags: php, post, curl, xmlhttprequest

I grabbed the following Post request with Fiddler, i only masked the URL because i dont want to make an advertisement

```
POST http://xyz.com/dialogs/track HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xyz.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-CSRFToken: uuihXszJrkrXwnCkLKKDNQ8BrPRDqXvU
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.xyz.com/referer/
Content-Length: 2
Cookie: csrftoken=uuihXszJrkrXwnCkLKKDNQ8BrPRDqXvU
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{}
```

I need a Tutorial (Link would be usefull) to "fake" this Request with Curl, i found some stuff on Google but nothing is working an i receive errors.

-EDIT-

```
$headers = array(
'POST http://www.example.com/dialogs/track HTTP/1.1',
'Host: www.example.com',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0',
'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Accept-Language: de',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'DNT: 1',
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
'X-CSRFToken: uuihXszJrkrXwnCkLKKDNQ8BrPRDqXvU',
'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
'Referer: http://www.example.com',
'Content-Length: 2',
'Cookie: __cfduid=d0db16cb5c4c58db770a1374f09a61d7d1375100590810; csrftoken=uuihXszJrkrXwnCkLKKDNQ8BrPRDqXvU; __utma=1.2111538523.1375265099.1375427020.1375431064.5; __utmz=1.1375348556.2.2.utmcsr=example.de|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/game/index.php; __gads=ID=88f0a0a8b0698e1e:T=1375265099:S=ALNI_MYX8OxkwPxXQd7VY4qDImLK7fq_yQ; __utmb=1.4.9.1375431089319; __utmc=1',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Pragma: no-cache',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'',
'{}'
);



//set POST variables
$url = 'http://www.example.com/dialogs/track';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
if (curl_error($ch)) {
print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
var_dump($data);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Error Message

> Error: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

-EDIT 2-

I played a little bit around and now the connection is working, but it seems that the CSRF Token is not submittet correctly i recieve an error!

> Forbidden (403)
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Is their a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please be more specific as to what you currently already have written, and exactly which errors you receive? That would help us in figuring out what it is you need to do next to get this working. You'll want to look at using `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(...));` for setting the headers exactly as they are in this request. Without more specific information, I guess http://codular.com/curl-with-php is the best I can point you at.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

I think your issue is not with `Curl` but with how `CSRF` verification works.

Lets say a request is made to a server the server sets a session (basically a string in a cookie that identifies you to data on the server). You then post that data back to the server, where it compares the `CSRF` token with the `SESSION` token linked to the `COOKIE` you also sent back.

There is only one possible session cookie in you request - `csrftoken` (the others belonging to google and cloudflare).

**That would mean that the CSRF Token and the Session Identifier (`csrftoken` value) are exactly the same i.e `uuihXszJrkrXwnCkLKKDNQ8BrPRDqXvU`, which is not how CSRF verification works.**

You would need to get the session cookie and CSRF token when the `GET` response is returned and send them both back, one as a `COOKIE` value, the other as `POST` value (possibly 2 header values, but 2 different values) when you make your `POST` request.